# Twitter returns truncated text

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I collected historical twitter data using twitter api ,tweepy for python.But later I realised that twitter truncates the text to 140 chars and to get full text we should use extended mode. With out using extended mode,I learnt that the full text can be extracted for truncated retweeted tweets using retweeted_status field.But is there any way to get full text from truncated tweets which are not retweeted?

Answer (score 1):

Any endpoint that returns Tweets supports the `tweet_mode=extended` parameter, you can use this to retrieve the full text.